# Why field is not updated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following query function:

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($id)->first();

    if($user->status == 1) {
        $status = 0;
    } else {
        $status = 1;
    }

    User::where("id", $id)->update(["status" => $status]);
```

When I see database table a field `status` is not updated to 1

Status filed has description:

```
status         | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1
```

Comment: is `status` mass assigned?? show us your user model

Comment: Yes, model is: `protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'api_token', 'phone', 'secondname', 'openSignal', 'status'
    ];`

Comment: is there any error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to toggle boolean property:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->status = !$user->status;
$user->save();
```

Or:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->status = $user->status === 1 ? 0 : 1;
$user->save();
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, but what cause was in my case?

Comment: @Amelia I've just tried your code in 5.3 and it updates the data, but as I've said in my original answer, you should remove `->first()` because it doesn't get a new instance of the object from DB for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you save the status from instantiated user object?

you can do this instead:

```
  $user = User::findOrFail($id)->first();

if($user->status == 1) {
    $status = 0;
} else {
    $status = 1;
}

$user->update(["status" => $status]);
```